# Jmeter TCP Sampler send request without waiting answer

Tags: java, tcp, jmeter

I have a question about the TCP Sampler: is there a way to send a TCP request, and continue the next action without waiting for an answer?

I want to do that because i send a "pong" request, and if this "pong" get a response doesn't work well the test.
The response of the "pong" (that i don't want to receive) is expected to be received by another sampler.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option of writing your own implementation of:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/tcp/sampler/AbstractTCPClient.html

Which would return an empty array or something else in read method.

Feel free to contribute it if you do so, also feel free to ask a question on jmeter user mailing list, we might open a bugzilla for it as an enhancement request.